# Powershell move file with backup (like mv --backup=numbered)

Tags: powershell, move, mv

I'm looking if there's a PS command that'd be equal to mv --backup=numbered, and can't find anything.

In essence, move 'file' to 'file.old', but if 'file.old' exists, 'file' should be moved to 'file.old.2'.

For now the closest I found is from this link: https://www.pdq.com/blog/copy-individual-files-and-rename-duplicates/:

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Temp\File.txt"
$DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File.txt"

If (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
    $i = 0
    While (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
        $i += 1
        $DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File$i.txt"
    }
} Else {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $DestinationFile -Force
}

Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Force
```

It seems quite awful to have this amount of code. Is there anything simpler available?

Comment: There is no built-in backup option for moving files in Powershell. Whats wrong with  that amount of code anyway? You could make a function that fits your needs and call it fancy way.

Comment: Well technically I can even write it in pure assembly, that's not the point :-)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is no built-in function to do that. However, it should not be a problem to use a function of your own for that purpose.

How about this:

```
function Copy-FileNumbered {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$SourceFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$DestinationFile
    )
    # get the directory of the destination file and create if it does not exist
    $directory = Split-Path -Path $DestinationFile -Parent
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $directory -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $directory -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    }

    $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($DestinationFile)
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($DestinationFile)    # this includes the dot
    $allFiles  = Get-ChildItem $directory | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
    $newFile = $baseName + $extension
    $count = 1
    while ($allFiles -contains $newFile) {
        $newFile = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $baseName, $count, $extension
        $count++
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination (Join-Path $directory $newFile) -Force 
}
```

This will create a new file in the destination like `File(1).txt`
Of course, if you rather have names like `File.2.txt`, just change the format template `"{0}({1}){2}"` to `"{0}.{1}{2}"`

Use the function like

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Temp\File.txt"
$DestinationFile = "C:\Temp\NonexistentDirectory\File.txt"
Copy-FileNumbered -SourceFile $SourceFile -DestinationFile $DestinationFile
```

Comment: That is some idea, but it boils down to the fact that I either have to write my own utility that mimics all of mv's switches that I need and distribute it on all machines I control, or I have to embed it in a script that I need to run. Not a deal breaker, just a bit... weird.

Comment: I see what you did there :-)